# Notepad++ interpretation of HTML tags in JQuery calls

Tags: jquery, html, notepad++

My Notepad++ has a problem interpreting JQuery call using HTML inside, see my code below. The line:
$("body").append(...); seems to not recognize the pair for the right parenthesis. If, However, I modify the ending tag to be < /div> (putting a space in front of "/") the problem goes away. Unfortunately, adding space is against HTML standard. What would be the workaround for that issue? Thanks.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Formula</title>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script>

    $("body").append(<div id="my_id"></div>);

    function my_function() { }

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an issue with Notepad++; it's an issue with your JavaScript syntax. You'll see that the syntax highlighting on your question is a bit off as well.

That HTML fragment needs to be in a string since you're using it as string data within a script:

```
$("body").append('<div id="my_id"></div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to enclose the div tags in quotes as well.

```
append("div id=\"my_id\"></div>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
 $("body").append(<div id="my_id"></div>);
```

to:

```
$("body").append("<div id='my_id'></div>");
```